# How to decode Base64 string to text in PHP?

Tags: php

Need to convert a Base64 encoded string (\x codes) to normal readable text.

For example:

```
Convert "\x62\141\x73\145\x36\64\x5f\144\x65\143\x6f\144\x65"
to "base64_decode".
```

How to do this with PHP. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to convert x-codes to text:

```
$xCodes = '\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5f\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65';
$result = preg_replace_callback("/(\\\\x)([0-9A-Fa-f]+)/u", function($matched) {
    return chr(hexdec($matched[2]));
}, $xCodes);

var_dump($result); // string(13) "base64_decode"
```