# API call on a binary IP address shows weird format when imported

Tags: php, mysql, api

Im doing an API GET call to get some IP addresses.
These are stored in a MySQL database, as Binary(16) type.
Example:

```
0x00000000000000000000ffff0104ce7f
```

As this is in HEX format, by converting `ffff0104ce7f` I get the IP address (in this instance it converts to `1.4.206.127`)

When I make the API GET call I get

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00??\x01\x04?\x7F
```

This is the hex i get, when trying to get the above mentioned IP address that is stored as

```
0x00000000000000000000ffff0104ce7f
```

in the database.

Im importing the data into a PHP website.

How do I convert the HEX string (`\x00\x00..`) into something readable in PHP, preferably an IP address as a string, e.g. `1.4.206.127`?

Comment: Possibly http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php

Comment: Wouldn't `ffff0104ce7f` be `255.255.1.4.206.127` though, or am I missing something?

Comment: Alternatively, use `base_convert()`. http://php.net/base-convert

Answer (score 0):

Above problem should have worked with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159115/how-to-convert-x-codes-to-text-in-php)

solution but apparently it didn't ... SO I am thinking maybe the response

`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00??\x01\x04?\x7F`

you are getting is not correct... but then I could be wrong!